# update field in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables test and test1

test

```
id formula 
1  A12+C32+D+X
2  K/Y
```

test1

```
    id Code 
    6  A12
    7  C32
   100 A1
    10 D
    12 X
    13 K
    14 Y
```

How can I update formula(text formlas) filed in the table `test` to get

```
 id formula 
    1  [6]+[7]+[10]+[12]
    2  [13]/[14]
```

Comment: Check [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0d8d0/1) SQLFiddle

Comment: it don't give the correct result http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/73ece/1

Comment: That's the second time you changed the requisite, how can I know you'll not change them again?

Comment: When I test on my database it  returns some exceptions , excuse me .

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could get was using TSQL. It uses a cursor to go over every row in the replacement table and updates the formula table.

```
declare @rid numeric
declare @rcode varchar

declare @getreplacement cursor
set @getreplacement = cursor for
select id, code
from test1 -- replacement

open @getreplacement
fetch next
from @getreplacement into @rid, @rcode

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  update test set formula = replace(f, @rcode, '['+cast(@rid as varchar)+']') -- replace formula
  fetch next
  from @getreplacement into @rid, @rcode
end

close @getreplacement
deallocate @getreplacement
go
```

Comment: I try your code, it works correctly but in case I have for example   id=6 Code=A12 it wouldn't work, I update my question .

Comment: But that was not your question... I will check later when I have some time.